# How to care for container bulbs after the first year?

Tags: container-gardening, bulbs

I live in Zone 9 (UK/Ireland).

There are plenty of tutorials online explaining how to plant freshing purchased bulbs in containers and how to care for them until the foliage dies. E.g. plant them in a container with drainage holes, fertiliser, and compost in the autumn and only water sparingly until the foliage grows in the spring. Let them bloom in the sun, and let the foliage die off naturally without cutting.

What's not clear to me is how to keep them thriving in subsequent years. Can they remain in a pot? Do they need a bigger pot etc. What if you don't want to plant them in the ground?